# regex: return characters inside parenthensis

Tags: regex, linux, unix, awk, grep

I can't seem to get the values inside a parenthesis using grep.

```
echo "(this is a string)" | grep -Eo '[a-z ]*'
```

Ideally that should return the value inside the parenthesis, "this is a astring", instead it is not returning anything. Does anyone know the explanation?

Comment: Works for me. What flavour of UNIX are you on?

Comment: When I type uname, it just returns 'Linux'. I'm unsure what flavour of UNIX I'm on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**This grep with -P (perl regex) works:**

```
echo "foo (this is a string) bar" | grep -Po '\(\K[^)]*'
this is a string
```

**OR using awk:**

```
echo "foo (this is a string) bar" | awk -F '[()]+' '{print $2}'
this is a string
```

**OR using sed:**

```
echo "foo (this is a string) bar" | sed 's/^.*(\(.*\)*).*$/\1/'
this is a string
```

Comment: the awk solution works perfectly great. thanks for the alternative!

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to match everything enclosed by the parentheses, not including the parentheses, you should use this grep:

```
grep -Po '(?<=\()[^\)]*?'
```

The `(?<=\()` is a negative look-behind assertion that tells the regex engine to start from a character preceded by an opening parenthesis. `[^\)]*?` tells it to match all characters until it encounters a closing parenthesis. The `-P` tells it to use Perl regex syntax.

Comment: echo "(this is a string)" | grep -Eo '(?<=\()[^\)]*?'

returns nothing

Comment: Try `grep -Po`. This is a Perl-style regex.